# How can I find both identical and similar strings in a particular field in a text file in Linux?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, uniq

My apologies ahead of time - I'm not sure that there is an answer for this one using only Linux command-line fu.  Please note I am not a programmer, but I have been playing around with bash and python a bit over the last few years.

I have a large text file with rows and columns that resemble the following (note - fields are separated with tabs):

```
1074    Beetle  OOB11061MNH 12/22/16    Confirmed   
3430    Hightop 0817BESTYET 08/07/17    Queued  
3431    Hightop 0817BESTYET 08/07/17    Queued  
3078    Copland 2017GENERAL 07/07/17    Confirmed   
3890    Bartok  FOODS   09/11/17    Confirmed
5440    Alphapha    00B1106IMNH 01/09/18    Queued
```

What I want to do is find and output only those rows where the third field is either identical OR similar to another in the list.  I don't really care whether the other fields are similar or not, but they should all be included in the output.  By similar, I mean no more than [n] characters are different in that particular field (for example, no more than 3 characters are different).  So the output I would want would be:

```
1074    Beetle  OOB11061MNH 12/22/16    Confirmed   
3430    Hightop 0817BESTYET 08/07/17    Queued  
3431    Hightop 0817BESTYET 08/07/17    Queued  
5440    Alphapha    00B1106IMNH 01/09/18    Queued
```

The line beginning 1074 has a third field that differs by 3 characters with 5440, so both of them are included.  3430 and 3431 are included because they are exactly identical.  3078 and 3890 are eliminated because they are not similar.

Through googling the forums I've managed to piece together this rather longish pipeline to be able to find all of the instances where field 3 is exactly identical:

```
cat inputfile.txt | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } {if (count[$3] > 1) print $0; else if (count[$3] == 1) { print save[$3]; print $0; } else save[$3] = $0; count[$3]++; }' > outputfile.txt
```

I must confess I don't really understand awk all that well; I'm just copying and adapting from the web.  But that seemed to work great at finding exact duplicates (i.e., it would output only 3430 and 3431 above).  But I have no idea how to approach trying to find strings that are not identical but that differ in no more than 3 places.

For instance, in my example above, it should match 1074 and 5440 because they would both fit the pattern:
    ??B1106?MNH

But I would want it to be able to match also any other random pattern of matches, as long as there are no more than three differences, like this:
    20?7G?N?RAL

These differences could be arbitrarily in any position.

The reason for needing this is we are trying to find a way to automatically find typographical errors in a serial-number-like field.  There might be a mis-key, or perhaps a letter "O" replaced with a number "0", or the like.

So... any ideas?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: how many lines in this file?

Comment: In the thousands.  At this point, around 6500 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this script

```
 $ more hamming.awk

  function hamming(x,y,xs,ys,min,max,h) {
    if(x==y) return 0;
    else {
      nx=split(x,xs,"");
      mx=split(y,ys,"");
      min=nx<mx?nx:mx;
      max=nx<mx?mx:nx;
      for(i=1;i<=min;i++) if(xs[i]!=ys[i]) h++;
      return h+(max-min);     
    }
  }  
  BEGIN   {FS=OFS="\t"}
  NR==FNR {
      if($3 in a) nrs[NR];
      for(k in a)
        if(hamming(k,$3)<4) {
           nrs[NR];
           nrs[a[k]];
        }
      a[$3]=NR;
      next
  }

  FNR in nrs
```

usage

```
$ awk -f hamming.awk file{,}
```

it's a double scan algorithm, finds the hamming distance (the one you described) between keys.  Notice the it's O(n^2) algorithm, so may not suitable for very large data sets.  However, not sure any other algorithm can do better.

**NB** Additional note based on the comment which I missed from the post. This algorithm compares the keys character by character, so displacements won't be identified.  For example `123` and `23` will give a distance of 3.

Comment: in case of a miss-key (OP mentions as possibility) hamming distance won't work

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I'll try this and see how well it works!  Honestly, even if it only catches some of the errors and not all of them it will be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @karakfa - I tried the script with the sample above, and it output only the line with 3431.  I just don't know awk well enough to follow what it's doing, but I did notice the line that says `if(hamming(k,**$1**)<4 {` uses the $1 variable instead of $3.  I tried changing $1 to $3 and it seems to have produced the output that I was looking for.  Was this the correct move?

Comment: yes, right.  I used `$1` for testing but forgot to change to `$3` in that place.  Also you may want to set the FS and OFS to tab; please see the changes above.

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein distance aka "edit distance" suits your task best. Perl script below requires installing a module Text::Levenshtein (for debian/ubuntu do: `sudo apt install libtext-levenshtein-perl`).

```
use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);                                                                                                                                                  

$maxdist = shift;                                                                
@ll = (<>);                                                                      
@k = map {                                                                       
    $k = (split /\t/, $_)[2];                                                    
    # $k =~ s/O/0/g;                                                             
} @ll;                                                                           
for ($i = 0; $i < @ll; ++$i) {                                                   
    for ($j = 0; $j < @ll; ++$j) {                                               
        if ($i != $j and distance($k[$i], $k[$j]) < $maxdist) {                  
            print $ll[$i];                                                       
            last;                                                                
        }                                                                        
    }                                                                            
}
```

Usage:

```
perl lev.pl 3 inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

The algorithm is the same O(n^2) as in @karakfa's post, but matching is more flexible.

Also note the commented line `# $k =~ s/O/0/g;`. If you uncomment it, then all O's in key will become 0's, which will fix keys damaged by O->0 transformation. When working with damaged data I always use small rules like this to fix data gradually, refining rules from run to run, to the point where data is almost perfect and fuzzy match is no longer needed.